# Is there a way to perform multioutput regression in Scikit-Learn using a different base estimator for each output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Consider a typical multi-output regression problem in Scikit-Learn where we have some input vector X, and output variables y1, y2, and y3. In Scikit-Learn that can be accomplished with something like:

```py
import sklearn.multioutput
model = sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor(
    estimator=some_estimator_here()
)
model.fit(X=train_x, y=train_y)
```

In this implementation, the estimator is copied and trained for each of the output variables. However, this does not allow for a case where different base estimators are used for each of the outputs.

Let's say we do more development on our model, and discover that one type of model (let's say XGBoost with Tweedie loss) is particularly well-suited for predicting y1, and another type of model is particularly well-suited for predicting y2 and y3 (let's say a kernelized RR). This cannot be accomplished using the Sklearn implementation of MultiOutputRegressor.

Ideally, the syntax would look something like this:

```py
import sklearn.multioutput, sklearn.kernel_ridge, xgboost
model = BetterMultiOutputRegressor(
    estimator = [
        xgboost.XGBRegressor(objective="reg:tweedie"),
        sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge(),
        sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge()
    ]
)
model.fit(X=train_x, y=train_y)
```

Where each index in the `estimator` argument would correspond to each index of the output vector.

Is there anything in Sklearn that could be used to accomplish this (including undocumented behavior), or any libraries in the Python ecosystem that do this?

Or is this behavior I'm going to need to implement myself?

Comment: How exactly is that different from fitting three single output regressors? (Which is what `MultiOutputRegressor()` does anyway.)

Comment: The difference is that sklearn's MultiOutputRegressor is much less verbose to use than training 3 separate regressors. It handles combining all of the outputs into a single vector, only one train call needs to be made, and only one predict call needs to be made. I'm going to just implement this behavior myself if it doesn't exist, but it would be nice to know if a library out there has already done this.